# Workflow 4 tracking records viewer

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

there was an application called 'WorkflowMonitor' that was included with the samples kit for workflow 3 which gave you a visual playback through previously run workflows.

The tracking records that app works against appear to be a different shape to those in workflow 4, is there a similar viewer that anyone knows of that can give me an insight into previously run workflows in workflow 4?

I am really just looking for the best way to interpret the data, the Workflow Monitor would have been perfect, but appears to be incompatible now.

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know near to nothing about WF3 but, based on your request, you might want to start by downloading [this WCF/WF Examples package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459).

Take a look at *WF\Application\VisualWorkflowTracking* solution to see a visual tracking system in action.

See also the concept of Workflow Tracking Participants on WF4, on these links:

- [Workflow Tracking and Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx)
- [Tracking Participants in .NET 4 Beta 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2009/07/14/tracking-participants-in-net-4-beta-1.aspx)

A small introduction from the first link:

> Windows Workflow tracking is a .NET Framework version 4 feature
>   designed to provide visibility into workflow execution. It provides a
>   tracking infrastructure to track the execution of a workflow instance.
>   The WF tracking infrastructure transparently instruments a workflow to
>   emit records reflecting key events during the execution. This
>   functionality is available by default for any .NET Framework 4
>   workflow.

The examples package contains a bunch of example code about tracking on WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Basic\Tracking folder.

Answer (score 0):

@Jota's answer is a good one, you should look at those examples. The visual tracking example is kind of a mess though. A few of us of done some different variations that separate the running of the workflow from the viewing of the tracking data.

http://geekswithblogs.net/JoshReuben/archive/2011/06/07/workflow-4.0.1-statemachine—distributed-tracking-visualization.aspx

https://github.com/PeteGoo/Workflow-Service-Tracking-Viewer

and my own version with signalR but based on the visual tracking sample 
http://panmanphil.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/slides-and-sample-from-the-chippewa-valley-code-camp/

Looks like you have some reading on your hands.