# Trace file isn't being created even though TraceEvent is called?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, workflow-foundation-4, system.diagnostics

### Objective

Use `System.Diagnostics` to perform tracing. Though I have used `log4net` and other logging solutions, I am only interested in getting tracing to work with `System.Diagnostics`.

### Problem

Even though I'm issuing the `TraceEvent` the file is not being created anywhere.

### Application Information

I have an application that's hosting some WF services. One of the services is a state machine with an initial state that looks like this:

[image: State Machine Initial State]

the `LogMessage` custom activity is also very straight forward. It receives four basic parameters:

[image: LogMessage Parameters]

defines the `TraceSource` as a variable:

[image: LogMessage TraceSource Variable]

and then simply calls `TraceEvent`:

[image: LogMessage TraceEvent Invocation]

### Configuration

The configuration for this `TraceSource` and `TraceListener` is as follows:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="log" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="file" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
               BaseFileName="gsf_workflows.txt"
               DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior="ThrowException"
               Location="Custom"
               CustomLocation="D:\Log"
               MaxFileSize="81920000"
               LogFileCreationSchedule="LogFileCreationScheduleOption.Daily"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Have you tried other traces to check the whole tracing thing works, and you're working on the proper .config file? Like the default one (OutputDebugString) plus a tool such as DbgView?

Comment: @SimonMourier, are you talking about the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx)?

Comment: No, the standard default trace listener internally uses OutputDebugString, and traces can be caught using DbgView. Do theses traces even work?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I got ya. No they don't work either.

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on this first. They should work (there is no required rights for writing to a file). Are you working on the good .config file?

Comment: @SimonMourier, will do, I'm using the `web.config` in the WF Service app.

Answer (score 10):

FYI for everyone stumbling on this page..

FileLogTraceListener will not create folders if they are missing.

FileLogTraceListener will not bypass security, your process identity will need create+modify permissions on the target folder.

It's "bad form" to target the executable folder, this tends to change depending on the host (for example, when writing under IIS Express you aren't writing to the same location as DevEnv, nor the hosted web app.)  One suggestion is that instead of "ExecutableLocation" you may want to opt for "Custom" and specify a particular path (such as X:\logfiles)

Writers flush to disk when their internal buffers fill, if memory serves me the default buffer size is 8KB. This is not a facet of trace listeners, but the underlying file stream it writes to.

Lastly, if you do not need the form and function of FileLogTraceListener, instead consider tracing to the EventLog (there is a listener for this) as this may be more accessible to other devs and non-devs (such as ops engineers, third party monitoring tools, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. In my current situation I'm running under IIS Express in Debug so it's running under my account and thus has all rights to the output folder (see my update I'm also now using a custom folder based off of feedback). However, I do in fact need the form and function of that listener because it rolls over logs and we do 100s of 1000s of transactions every day.

Comment: I believe log4net has adapters so that it can function as a trace listener. I mention it because you may be familiar, and because in my own experience the in-built filelogtracelistener (among others) will experience performance problems under extreme load (in terms of bus i/o and disk/thread contention, resource utilization, etc). It blocks writers with a lock/Cs/Monitor (and, thus, it writes loglines out-of-order cross-thread), it doesn't overlap writes, it holds a lock during file rollovers. In effect FileLogTraceListener is a process-wide, non-order-preserving, disk bound shared lock.

Comment: For reference; I've maintained and implemented systems that handled 8-40k requests/sec sustained and a poor choice in logging provider can quickly murder a high-load system. I still use it despite having been griefed by it so many times since 99% of the systems out there barely do 1000 requests/sec burst, and I prefer the .NET Tracing framework. If you stick with the in-built listener my suggestion is you reflect the source code, copy it, paste it into a new source file and use your self-compiled version instead. You should expect to need to modify it at some point down the road.

Comment: @ShaunWilson You are a godsend --either the doc doesn't mention or I didn't see that you have to flush the writer to make it actually write to disk.

Comment: @ShaunWilson Custom listener does not create a log file for  initializeData="CustomWeblog.txt", but  initializeData="d:\CustomWeblog.txt" triggers log file creation. What can be the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821407/tracesource-custom-listener-does-not-create-a-log-file-for-relative-path-but-wo

Comment: @Spirit - `InitializeData` property is not something you should need to use with `FileLogTraceListener` (this differs from your linked question, which uses a different TraceListener class), `FileLogTraceListener` would instead use use `BaseFileName="CustomWeblog.txt"`, `Location="Custom"` and `CustomLocation="D:\"` --- it's worth noting by default if you do not specify a path "current working directory" is used, perhaps your log files are created in the CWD for iisexpress (or etc) and not where you would expect them to be created.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

**1) Your workflow is most likely stopping due to exceptions because your *.config* file is not right. Note the changes:**

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="log" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <add name="file" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, 
                         Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, 
                         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             BaseFileName="gsf_workflows.txt"
             DiskSpaceExhaustedBehavior="ThrowException"
             Location="ExecutableDirectory"
             MaxFileSize="81920000"
             LogFileCreationSchedule="Daily"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

**2) You've to flush the listeners, otherwise they won't be written. You can do it in two ways.**

Explicitly call [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.flush.aspx) method on your *logger* variable using again *InvokeMethod* activity.

OR

Turn on auto flush on config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    ....
</system.diagnostics>
```

---

That being said, I don't know if you're aware of [Workflow Tracking and Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992%28VS.100%29.aspx) capabilities. It looks a good fit for your needs. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326380/87825) answer for more links and examples.

Comment: As an aside, it should not be necessary to use a full name (Version, Culture, token, etc) a partial name is sufficient. Although the location, schedule and options derive from Enums internally, if you look at the code the interpretation of the config section is by string matching exclusively. This is why using fully qualified names for creation schedule and location would not be working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer friend, and I didn't include the `autoFlush` because in PROD I don't want to `autoFlush`. However, even after adding the `autoFlush` and modifying the *.config* file as you stated it still doesn't work. FYI, I did go ahead and go with a custom folder like you said too.