# TraceSource : Custom TraceListener not working

Tags: asp.net, debugging, system.diagnostics, tracesource

I'm using TraceSource to log the ASP.Net application. 
 To change the output format I need to create own TraceListener instead of TextwriterListener.

```
   <trace>
        <listeners>
            <remove name="Default" />
             <add name="Default"
             type="WebTracing.CustomTraceListener, WebTracing" initializeData="Weblog.txt" traceOutputOptions="None"/>
        </listeners>
    </trace>

 public class CustomTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
 {
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        if (NeedIndent)
        {
            WriteIndent();
        }
        message = //customize format
        base.Write(message); 
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (NeedIndent)
        {
            WriteIndent();
        }
        message = //customize format
        base.WriteLine(message);
        NeedIndent = true;
    }
 }
```

// Invoke

```
        CustomTraceListener obj = new CustomTraceListener();
        obj.TraceEvent(null, "This is a critical message", TraceEventType.Critical, 0);
        (or)
         obj.Write( "This is a critical message");
        obj.Close();
```

No Error. No data printed in output file. 
  I'm new to ASP.Net , Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

**update**

---

I tried another way. But results in Configuration error.

```
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="Trace" switchName="mySwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">    
      <listeners>
        <remove name="Default" />
        <add name="Default"
             type="WebTracing.CustomTraceListener, WebTracing" initializeData="Weblog.txt" traceOutputOptions="None"/>
      </listeners>      
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="mySwitch" value="All"/>
</switches>


        TraceSource obj = new TraceSource("Trace");
        obj.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical,0,"This is a critical message");
        obj.Close();
```

**Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not create WebTracing.CustomTraceListener, WebTracing.**

***Note: Normal TextWriterListener is working fine. But i need custom listener to format the output string.***

Comment: Did you solve it by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add public modifier to your class

And you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write method
```

Comment: happy to help you but have you checed on output windows

Comment: Trace.write() shows in output window.not in file.Normal TextWriterListener is working fine with TraceSource. But i need CustomListener which extends TextWriterListener to format the output.Pls See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write directly to the Trace Listener. In this case, the System.Diagnostic.Trace object writes to the Trace Listener.  If you were using TraceSources, then you'd write to the trace source and the config file let's the TraceSource know which listeners are register for receiving trace info.

Also, you are writing to a file, which usually has a flush interval, so you might want to make sure that it is autoflushing, or in your tests, write enough data to trigger a flush (when the data is written to file).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i use System.Diagnostic.Trace it wont fire my customListener's overriden methods and obviously it writes nothing in output file.See my update i have tried with TraceSource, it is working for Default textwriterListener but not for customListener.

Comment: Another possibility is the type is wrong.  Sometimes you have to fiddle with the assembly and type. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/352679/Get-Assembly-full-name-from-Visual-Studio-VersionN   Sorry I didn't have time to create a sample app & test my theory.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your relative path `initializeData="Weblog.txt"` to absolute `initializeData="d:\Weblog.txt"`. I am still trying to detect the root reason why creation of custom-listner log files does not work for us.

I guess this might be because of not configured project folder permissions: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512241/1145224).

---

I have reproduced the same issue today and I see that your application is configured in the right way. It took me several hours to understand that **the proper configuration is not sufficient condition for creating log files using custom-listeners**.

When I execute **TextWriterTraceListener** the log is created in the project's folder.
But **CustomTextWriterTraceListener** does not create anything.

---

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this scenario, after adding the below snippets of code after `<source>` tag, it worked writing to the text file as mentioned

```
<switches>
      <add name="mySwitch" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Here is the the partial snippets from **Web.config** file

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
  <sources>
    <source name="myTraceSource" switchName="mySwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" >
      <listeners>
        <clear/>
        <add name="textwriterListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="d:\outfile1.txt" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime, Callstack" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="mySwitch" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Further, I had invoking `TraceSource` inside some method defined by creating a static object

```
static TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("myTraceSource");
...

ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical,0,"This is a critical message");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the configuration and implementation.

If you configure your logger as

```
<listeners>
        <remove name="Default" />
         <add name="Default"
         type="WebTracing.CustomTraceListener, WebTracing" initializeData="Weblog.txt"/>
</listeners>
```

your custom implementation should have a matching public constructor:

```
public CustomTraceListener(string initializeData)
{
    //configure your listener using the initializeData value
}
```

In other case, the ConfigurationErrorsException will be thrown.