# TextWriterTraceListener not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace, diagnostics

I am trying to add tracing to my .net 4.5 ASP.NET MVC project. What I did:

(web.config)

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <sources>
      <source name="TraceSource" switchName="Switch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="TextWriter" initializeData="C:\log\trace.log" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime, Callstack"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="Switch" value="Warning"/>
    </switches>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

In the class that should write into the log:

```
ts = new TraceSource("TraceSource");
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "Authenticating as user: " + CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.ToString()); Trace.Flush();
```

So basically,

- I added the Listener to the TraceSource in the web.config,
- set autoflush to true,
- init the TraceSource in the class and then write to it.
- debugged through it and saw that the TraceSource is correctly initialized.
- checked DbgView (SysInternals) but I see nothing.
- checked with ProcessMonitor if the log file gets created somewhere. Nothing.
- tried different paths
- looked in the application folder, in system32 and of course in the specified folders.

Further Information:

- Impersonate = true
- Local dev machine
- IIS Express, Visual Studio 2013
- TRACE constant is set in debug and release

What am I missing? Why is it still not working?

Comment: When are you calling the Trace Source's Flush. i.e. ts.Flush()?

Comment: Autoflush is true. I also tried manually flushing, but that does also not work. @Krishna

Comment: sorry missed that - does IISExpress User has access to this file "C:\log\trace.log"?

Comment: Also can you try logging with a bigger message, I found this link that seems to explain more along the sameline. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502960/trace-file-isnt-being-created-even-though-traceevent-is-called

Comment: IISExpress runs in the administrator user.

I also saw that link, but I could not see anything that I did not know yet. Could you specify what you mean? @Krishna

Comment: the answer suggests that TextWriter Listner is dumping messages after the stream reached over 8k.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your switch statement prevents the output.

Your switch value is "Warning" where else your TraceEventType is "Information".

Try changing the switch value to "Information" or "Verbose".