# Unify logging not writing to file

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I have the following sample code that works fine:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var traceListener = new FlatFileTraceListener("unifylogging.log",
        "--------------------",
        "-----------------------------");

    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    config.AddLogSource("My Log Source", SourceLevels.All, true).AddTraceListener(traceListener);

    var logger = new LogWriter(config);

    logger.Write("This is a test");
}
```

However, if I change the `logger.Write` call to one pulled straight from the manual it doesn't write anything:

```
logger.Write("Log entry with a category, priority, event ID,severity, and title.",
    "General",
    8,
    9003,
    TraceEventType.Warning,
    "Logging Block Examples");
```

I have also tried this with the `ConsoleTraceListener`, and with some of the other overloads of the `Write` methods including:

- `logger.Write("Hello from unify", "Cat1");`
- `logger.Write("Hello from unify", new[] { "Cat1" });`

The only one that works is the `Write(string)`.

> **NB**  The suggested duplicate is with regards to Workflow Foundation and seems to be about the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` tracing.  This is about Unify Logging.

Comment: Is it just sitting in the buffer?  Trace.Flush?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trace file isn't being created even though TraceEvent is called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502960/trace-file-isnt-being-created-even-though-traceevent-is-called)

Comment: @Mick I tried adding `traceListener.Flush();` after the the write statement with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's some odd naming going on.  The `name` parameter in the  `.AddLogSource(string name)` method *actually* defines the categories that this config will collect.

Therefore, by changing the categories to match the log source like so:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var traceListener = new ConsoleTraceListener();

    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    config.AddLogSource("My Log Source", SourceLevels.All, true).AddTraceListener(traceListener);

    var logger = new LogWriter(config);

    logger.Write("This is a log.", "My Log Source");
}
```

Will produce the expected logs.